# Regex not working with similar looking string

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the content between Start and End tag for the below mentioned strings

```
<a href="./products/" class="link">Products </a>

<a href="./servicesandsolutions/" class="link">Services & Solution </a>
```

Regex used:

```
<([a-z0-9]+)([^<]+)\*(?:>(.\*?)</\\2>|\\D+/>)
```

It is working fine for the first string but not with the later once

Comment: @LevLevitsky: I think your edits introduced several errors into the regex. What's with all the backslashes?

Comment: Reverted to the original regexp. LevLevitsky, why would you change it that significantly?

Comment: Once I've removed the backslashes I've got regex storm complaining about inefficiency. It could be that it doesn't work with the second because it is longer - and the inefficiencies in the expression is causing it to tip over into timing out

Comment: How is it working fine? I can't see this expression working for any of your examples.

Comment: Do you want to get the content of the tags? Like `Products ` in the 1st example and `Services & Solution ` in the 2nd?

Comment: @KL-7, see http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/df75403e-8c91-4728-a78d-f1f63ec73f69/view-source `</\\2>` is intended, and probably the slashes also. I'm guessing OP is copying a quoted expression.

Comment: @Qtax, well, looks like I didn't help. Reverted my changes. But these slashes are obviously should not be there.

Comment: Guys, I don't know what happened but I only added spaces before the regex. Sorry about the weird effects.

Comment: @KL-7 yes my intention was to get contents like 'Product' and 'Service & Solution'

Answer (score 1):

Why so complex? Won't simple `/>([^<]+)</` capture the content of an element?

Comment: Doesn't work with `'<a href="./products/" class="link"> <b>Products</b> </a>'`.

Comment: ... and with thousands of other cases as well, yes. But are we supposed to re-write the HTML parser in regexes (yet again) - or just solve a simple specific case here?

Comment: The point is we cannot close a task before knowing all the details. I said that many times here: **it's no point trying to construct the universal solution if the OP doesn't need it!** It's much more simple to iterate over intended use-cases until you both get the result we need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the flavour of regex - use lookahead and lookbehind methods to get just the match between > and < i.e.

```
(?<=>)[^>]*(?=<)
```

`(?<=>)` - looks ahead for a >

`(?=<)` - looks behind for a <

`[^>]*` - matches the text in the link itself

lookahead and lookbehind are zero width matches so will will just get what you need

Comment: +1 for simplicity, although lookbehinds are not supported by many popular regex tools (and Javascript is, sadly, one of them). But then again, which platform will the OP use is a mystery...

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the tags.

```
var str = '<a href="./products/" class="link">Products </a>'
var str2 = '<a href="./servicesandsolutions/" class="link">Services & Solution </a>'
var RE_findOpenAndCloseTag = /^<[^>]+>|<\/[^>]>$/g;

str.replace( RE_findOpenAndCloseTag, '' ) == "Products ";
str2.replace( RE_findOpenAndCloseTag, '' ) == "Services & Solution ";
```

Note that `RE_findOpenAndCloseTag` assumes that tags will always start with a `<` and not contain an `>` unless it's closing the tag.
Thus this will fail.
'>">This will fail

But an easier way would be to convert the tags into a node, then get the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't want to parse HTML your self with regex, parser are better at that.

Assuming you are using PCRE here's a random guess at the expression you are looking for:

```
(?is)<([a-z]+)\b[^<>]*(?:>(.*?)</\1>|/>)
```

Note that this will not work with nested tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will resolve your issue (Just Add `|</\1>`)

```
<([a-z0-9]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*?)|\D+/>|</\1>)
```

[For more detail please refer](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)